# Seeking: Firefox pluggin to email a screenshot of the *whole screen* (not just browser)

Tags: screenshot, firefox-3

If find frequent need to send a screenshot of my entire screen to someone via email. And I use Gmail so I can't just paste a screen capture in, I have to open an image editor, paste, save, open Gmail, browse, drill down and select the file.

I fond a few FF pluggins that do a nice job but only capture the *browser*.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox won't be able to capture anything except the browser. You need to get your OS to do that for you. For example, on Windows, pressing the 'Print Screen' (PrtScn) key - that will copy a screenshot to the clipboard. On OSX, use command-shift-3.

Comment: not entirely true: one could craft an NPAPI based plugin to perform the required functionality.

Comment: It can do it if you use XPCOM, with a native DLL.

Comment: Either way, you have to use native code, as FF add-ons cannot do this (for security reasons).